# I'm having trouble with creating a family tree in c#

Tags: c#, tree

Here what I have, a person class with their parents and their children. I want to create a method that creates a dictionary with a person's relatives and their "closeness" to any given person using how closely related they are to the subject. What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to iterate through all of a person's in a situation where a person had living parents and children, that's where you come in, how do I do this new fangled up-down iteration. Anyway here's the code that I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace familytree{

    public static Random rand = new Random();

    public class Program{

        public static void main(string[] args){


        }

        public static void relatives(Person subject){
            // help

        }

    }



    public class Person{

        public readonly bool gender;
        public string firstname;
        public string lastname;
        public Person[] parents = new Person[2];
        public List<Person> children = new List<Person>();

        public Person(Person mother, Person father){

            this.gender = rand.NextDouble() >= 0.5;
            this.parents[0] = mother;
            this.parents[1] = father;
            this.firstname = "firstname";
            this.lastname = father.lastname + " - " + mother.lastname;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the sample input and expected output?

Comment: So I just want to make an List<Person> of all of the subject's relatives? (I guess I should change the void in the relatives method to reflect that)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically you have to understand that each "Person Node" has 4 relations to other Person Nodes, Parents, Spouses, Children, and Siblings (Which we can refer to as Parents.Children excluding self). So now we can iterate through all of a Person Node's relatives using a recursive method that looks like this:

```
        public static bool contains<T>(List<T> main, T sub) {

            foreach (T i in main) {
                if (i.Equals(sub)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static List<Person> relatives(Person person, List<Person> people) {

            // Spouses -> Children -> Siblings -> Parents
            // If Dead do not add to list but still iterate through

            if (person.alive) {
                people.Add(person);
            }

            // Spouces
            if (person.spouses.Count > 0) {
                foreach (Person spouse in person.spouses) {

                    if (spouse.alive) {
                        people.Add(spouse);
                    }

                    if (!contains<Person>(people, spouse)) people.AddRange(relatives(spouse, people));
                }
            }

            // Children
            if (person.children.Count > 0) {
                foreach (Person child in person.children) {

                    if (child.alive) {
                        people.Add(child);
                    }

                    if (!contains<Person>(people, child)) people.AddRange(relatives(child, people));
                }
            }

            // Parents
            if (person.parents[0] != null && person.parents[1] != null) {
                foreach (Person parent in person.parents) {

                    if (parent.alive) {
                        people.Add(parent);
                    }

                    if (!contains<Person>(people, parent)) people.AddRange(relatives(parent, people));

                    foreach (Person child in parent.children) {

                        if (child.alive) {
                            people.Add(child);
                        }

                        if (!contains<Person>(people, child)) people.AddRange(relatives(child, people));
                    }
                }
            }

            List<Person> family = new List<Person>();
            foreach (Person i in people) {
                bool copy = false;
                foreach (Person j in family) {
                    if (j == i) {
                        copy = true;
                    }
                }
                if (copy == false) {
                    family.Add(i);
                }
            }

            return family;
        }
    }
```